# DynamoDB table scan based on dates - Java

Tags: java, date, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a requirement, in my application, whereby I need to check a DynamoDB table for updates at regular intervals. Precisely, The field I need to check is not the hash key, and therefore I cannot query -- I need to scan.
The scan filter I am trying to build needs to check a field containing a date (coded as a String in the table), and the logic I am using is the one of asking all records created or updated in the last hour. The snippet I am using is below:

```
 Condition scanFilterCondition = new Condition()
.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.BETWEEN.toString())
.withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(new Date(currentTime-3600000).toString()), 
new AttributeValue().withS(new Date(currentTime).toString()));
```

It seems to be correct, however it seems to always return an empty set so it is ovviously not correct.

I've been googling around to understand why this is not correct, however I haven't found anything around scanning/querying DyanmoDB on dates.

Any ideas on the fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the string written in the table as an EPOCH timestamp (e.g. 1382199953)? with or without milliseconds?

The default `toString()` returns a locale-based human-readable string (e.g. `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`).

If that's not the case, please comment with a sample data from the field in question.

Edit to support [ISODateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) format using Joda:

`DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZoneUTC();`
`String isoDate = dateFormatter.print(currentTime);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, dates on the DynamoDB table are not written in millis. A sample date is 

"2013-10-18T17:49:28.918Z"

Thanks!

Comment: Added support for ISODateTime like you have in your DynamoDB - hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, don't really get your comment. Are you suggesting we add such support?

Comment: no - I meant I have edited my answer (see above) to include a code that Creates a string in the same format as the one found in your DynamoDB field